# Placement of labels in a panel winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, panel

I have a panel in winforms app in which I want to display some data in vertical alignment. I will get that data from XML document. I'll loop through XML like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
{
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = node.ChildNodes[i].Name + " = " + node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText;
    panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

At the end I can see only the first record displayed at the top left corner of the panel, but looping through the `panel1.controls`, I can see the count is 79, I just need to position them correctly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is extremely wasteful of resources.  Use a ListBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) instead and set its [FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowdirection.aspx) property to `TopDown`.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `FlowLayoutPanel` instead of it.
- Set to `FlowDirection` property to `TopDown`.

Comment: I tried that but I am getting two labels per one row, I want one label per row. Any idea how can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: @Laziale Then use a `TableLayoutPanel` that has two columns.  Also, that's the kind of thing that you should include in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to set the top and/or left properties of the label objects.

```
for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {

                lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = node.ChildNodes[i].Name + " = " + node.ChildNodes[i].InnerText;
                lbl.top = 15 * i;
                panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: Manually setting the location of everything would be a big mess. You should use a panel that's specifically designed for laying out controls like this. Way less work, much more maintainable, and creates a better output (i.e. what happens when the form is resized or you want to add something else just above the top label?).

Comment: it depends.  I saw the answer about the panel, but there is more flexibility with this one.  Different ways to do the same thing!

Comment: There might be occasional extreme cases where it's appropriate to set the location of each of your controls specifically, but as a rule you should avoid it like the plague.  None, or very, very few controls on your form should have an absolute location in a well designed and flexible application.  Absolute positioning results in forms that can't ever be resized, don't have movable components or dynamically sized content.  That's just not realistic for most applications.  Updating absolute positions in such situations is practically impossible.